# Yandex MAP API + Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно сделать фильтр меток на карте, используя Yandex map API. Вопрос заключается в том, что нужно вывести данные из базы и потом, используя фильтры, выводить или скрывать метки на карте.
Я вывел метки  на карту и добавил фильтры, но как сделать чтобы метки скрывались не понимаю, прошу помощи или подсказки как мне это реализовать.
Вот код как сейчас это работает:

```
<script>    
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [59.9386300, 30.3141300],
            zoom: 9,
             controls: []
        }); 
    var arrList = $('#prof_ul li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

    var arrList2 = $('#obr_ul li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

    var arrList3 = $('#napravlenie_ul li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

    // Создадим 5 пунктов выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems = arrList
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список, содержащий 5 пунктов.
        listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр по профессиям',
                title: 'Фильтр по профессиям'
            },
            items: listBoxItems,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: true,
                filters: listBoxItems.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);



        // Создадим 5 пунктов выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems2 = arrList2
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список, содержащий 5 пунктов.
        listBoxControl2 = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр по образовательному учереждению',
                title: 'Фильтр по образовательному учереждению'
            },
            items: listBoxItems2,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: true,
                filters: listBoxItems2.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl2);



        // Создадим 5 пунктов выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems3 = arrList3
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список, содержащий 5 пунктов.
        listBoxControl3 = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр по направлению',
                title: 'Фильтр по направлению'
            },
            items: listBoxItems3,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: true,
                filters: listBoxItems3.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl3);


     // Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка под номером #3 .
    listBoxControl3.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
        var listBoxItem3 = e.get('target');
        var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl3.state.get('filters'));
        filters[listBoxItem3.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem3.isSelected();
        listBoxControl3.state.set('filters', filters);
    });

    var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl3.state);
    filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
        // Применим фильтр.
        objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
    });

    function getFilterFunction(categories){
        return function(obj){
            var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
            return categories[content]
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function (data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });


    <?php 

foreach ($maps as $maps) {
    print '
        // Собственное изображение для метки с контентом
    var placemark'.$maps['id'].' = new ymaps.Placemark('.$maps['cardination'].', {
        hintContent: "Улица: '.$maps['street'].' <br> Организация : '.$maps['name'].' <br> Категория: '.$maps['category'].'",
        "balloonContent": "'.$maps['prof'].'", "clusterCaption": "'.$maps['zavedenie'].'", "iconCaption": "'.$maps['naprav'].'",
    }, {
        // Опции.
 
        // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
        iconLayout: "default#image",
 
        // Своё изображение иконки метки.
        iconImageHref: "'.$maps['image'].'",
        // Размеры метки.
        iconImageSize: [32, 32],
        // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
        // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
        iconImageOffset: [-16, -16],
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark'.$maps['id'].');
    ';
 }
    ?>



}); 


</script>
```

Код взят и адаптирован с официальной страницы api yandex, я так понимаю нужно получить файл json вот в этой строке

```
$.ajax({
            url: "data.php"
        }).done(function (data) {
            objectManager.add(data);
        });
```

но как мне это сделать, связав с базой?

Формат json файла должен выглядеть так:

```
{"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.831903, 37.411961]}, "properties": {"balloonContent": "Аптека", "clusterCaption": "Аптека", "hintContent": "Аптека", "iconCaption": "Аптека"}, "options": {"preset": "islands#blueCircleDotIconWithCaption"}})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил  вопрос, теперь я получаю значение но не могу скрыть метки которые нужно если кто знает подскажите.

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [59.9386300, 30.3141300],
            zoom: 9,
             controls: []
        }); 


    <?php 

foreach ($maps as $maps) {
    if($maps['prof'] == 1) {
    print '
        // Собственное изображение для метки с контентом
    var placemark'.$maps['id'].' = new ymaps.Placemark('.$maps['cardination'].', {
        hintContent: "Улица: '.$maps['street'].' <br> Организация : '.$maps['name'].' <br> Категория: '.$maps['category'].'",
        "balloonContent": "'.$maps['prof'].'", "clusterCaption": "'.$maps['zavedenie'].'", "iconCaption": "'.$maps['naprav'].'",
    }, {
        // Опции.

        // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
        iconLayout: "default#image",

        // Своё изображение иконки метки.
        iconImageHref: "'.$maps['image'].'",
        // Размеры метки.
        iconImageSize: [32, 32],
        // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
        // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
        iconImageOffset: [-16, -16],
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(placemark'.$maps['id'].');
    ';
 }

}
    ?>



    var arrList = $('#prof_ul li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

    var arrList2 = $('#obr_ul li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

    var arrList3 = $('#napravlenie_ul li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('id');
        }).get();

    // Создадим 5 пунктов выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems = arrList
        .map(function(title) {
            return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                data: {
                    content: title
                },
                state: {
                    selected: true
                }
            })
        }),
        // Теперь создадим список, содержащий 5 пунктов.
        listBoxControl = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
            data: {
                content: 'Фильтр по профессиям',
                title: 'Фильтр по профессиям'
            },
            items: listBoxItems,
            state: {
                // Признак, развернут ли список.
                expanded: true,
                filters: listBoxItems.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
                    filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
                    return filters;
                }, {})
            }
        });
    myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl);


      listBoxControl.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function (e) {

            var selectedFilters = listBoxControl.filter(function (it) {

                return it.isSelected();

            });

            applyFilters(selectedFilters);

        });



        function applyFilters(filters,myMap,geoObjects) {

            filters.forEach(function (filter,myMap,geoObjects) {


                <?php 

                foreach ($prof_main as $prof_main) {
                    print '
                        if(filter.data.get("content") == '.$prof_main['name'].') {
                          console.log("'.$prof_main['name'].'");
                             for (var i = 0; i< geoObjects.length; i++) {
                                console.log(i);
                                geoObject.options.set("visible", false);    
                            }

                        }

                    ';
                }

                ?>



            })

        }







}); 


</script>
```